# How to insert a large number of records quickly using ADO.Net Entity Model?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am using the ADO.Net Entity Model. Everytime I create a record, I am calling _entity.AddToTable(object); _entity.SaveChanges();

What is the fastest way of inserting the data? Is there any "batch" or "SqlBulkCopy" option for entity model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transactions.

[How to: Manage Transactions in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx)

Comment: I ended up just using SqlBulkCopy instead of the entity framework for this operation. But i'll give you the accepted answer since it is a faster way of doing it within the entity model.